# Mongodb Epoch Date - java mapping

Tags: java, mongodb, date, mapping, epoch

I would like to store dates in mongodb in epoch format (Unix time in secs or millisec, eg : "1433323417000") and have an object mapping in java java.util.Date Format (or joda.time.DateTime).
Can you let me know if this is possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MongoDb documentation :

> Internally, Date objects are stored as a 64 bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), which results in a representable date range of about 290 millions years into the past and future.
>   https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Date/

You can find some examples on how to insert using the Java driver [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/insert/)

On a read, there is nothing stopping you from converting the date to any format you want.

Comment: Thanks . I made a mistake by not converting my epoch date to Date() after the import was made in mongodb.. which was my fault.

Comment: glad it helped. was just about to say that ISOData is the default wrapper so you won't see epoch unless you explicitly convert to it. cheers for the vote!